# warning: Attempt to present modal when notification is called

Tags: ios, iphone

i am calling `presentModal` method on `viewDidAppear` using :

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self         
                                             selector:@selector(presentModal)         
                                                 name:@"xxxxxxx"         
                                               object:nil];

-(void)presentModal 
{
    PickerModalViewController *pickerModalViewController = [Appdelegate.window.rootViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PickerModalViewController"];

    pickerType = 2;
    pickerModalViewController.choices = self.localArray;
    pickerModalViewController.buttonTag = pickerType;

    pickerModalViewController.delegate = self;
    self.pickerPresenter = self;

    if (self.pickerPresenter) {
        [self.pickerPresenter presentViewController:pickerModalViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

when picker is presented it gives me a waring in both device and simulator

Warning: `Attempt to present PickerModalViewController: 0x10ec7280  on     UINavigationController: 0x90ad610 while a presentation is in progress!`

Answer (score 0):

The warning says to you, what is wrong. 
To avoid this warning you can use `delegate` property of UINavigationController and implement

`- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
       didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
                    animated:(BOOL)animated`